# Regex for English and Arabic combined

Tags: java, regex, spring, validation, passwords

How to write regular expressions for the below-mentioned use cases?

- String contains at least one Arabic character
- String contains at least one Arabic numeral

I need two separate regexes as I need to perform logic based on that.

This will be used in Java

> Tried (\u0660-\u0669) and [\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufc3f]|[\ufe70-\ufefc] to check for Arabic character but does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Matcher#find()`, you may match the strings with

```
String arabic_letter = "[\\p{InArabic}&&\\p{L}]";
String arabic_digit = "[\\p{InArabic}&&\\p{N}]";
```

Example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(arabic_letter);
Matcher m = p.matcher(your_string);
if (m.find()) {
    // the string contains an Arabic letter
}
```

You may also use the regex in `String#matches` with a slight modification:

```
s.matches("(?s).*[\\p{InArabic}&&\\p{L}].*")
s.matches("(?s)[^\\p{InArabic}&&\\p{L}]*[\\p{InArabic}&&\\p{L}].*")
```